# Get all assignments for Mechanical Turk using the .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm looking at the .NET API for Mechanical Turk and I want to create a simple review app that lets people accept or reject any assignments that are pending review. It looks like I can get all the hits with `client.GetAllHITs()`, but the only available method I see for assignments is `client.GetAllAssignmentsForHIT(hitid)`.

Does this mean that I'll have to make a separate call for every HIT? Is there any way to make a single batch call to get all assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to make a call for each HIT.